# JSTL цикл в JSP

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl

Есть необходимость запустить цикл с использованием begin и end, в качестве конечного значения из модели (model) извлекаю атрибут countDay (который возвращает одномерный массив) и пытаюсь получить значение элемента этого массива. Если извлекаю элементы массива вот так

```
<*a>${countDay[monthOfYear]}<*/a>
```

Всё ок, но как данные для цикла не получается. Код ниже:

```
<c:set var="dayInMonth" value="${countDay[monthOfYear]}"/> 
<c:forEach var="day" begin="1" end="${dayInMonth}">
   <div class="dayClass">${day}</div>
</c:forEach>
```

Подскажите как можно получить данные, которые можно использовать в качестве параметра в цикле.